# SwiftUI: How to center NavigationLink inside of a Form

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-form

Apologies if this has been asked/answered; I am trying to present a NavigationLink inside of a form, but would like it to be centered.  I can do this with a Button using HStack and Spacers;  the NavigationLink is a tat more stubborn:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                HStack {

                    //BUTTON CENTERS WITH SPACERS

                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {}, label: {
                        Text("Button")
                    })
                    Spacer()
                }
                
                HStack {

                    //NAVIGATIONLINK IGNORES SPACERS

                    Spacer()
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: Text("Destination"),
                        label: {
                     Text("Navigate")    
                    })
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: NavigationLink will not center in Form]

Comment: Are you wanting the "Navigate" text and the disclosure indicator horizontally centered? That's the intended look of a `NavigationLink`, standard across iOS.

Comment: @George_E I want it to look like a button (centered, sans the ">"). If the link is not in a View with a Form, it centers fine.  I also tried wrapping the Form in a VStack, with the link outside of the Form...this lets me center, but forces the link to bottom of the screen (ignoring any vertical spacers after the link).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way that I like to do this is by creating an empty navigation link.

```
@State var someBoolBinding = false

//Body

NavigationLink(destination: YourDestView(), isActive: $someBoolBinding) {}
```

Then create a custom button with a toggle.

```
Button("Go Here") {
   someBoolBinding.toggle()
}
```

You can use any button, even custom ones, or even an onTapGesture, just by changing that boolean value. From there it's as simple as centering as you would any other element and you don't have to rely on the "Navigation Link" style that you're being presented with. Alternatively you can do something like this.

```
 NavigationLink(destination: RegisterWithEmailView(), isActive: $someBoolBinding) {
                        Button("Go To some View", action: {
                            someBoolBinding.toggle()
                        })
                    }
```